# Not able to find the element by id or name in selinium java chrome browser

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

```
   public class Bwinbe {
            public static void main(String[] args) {    
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "mypath");
                WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
                driver.get("http://test.www.bwin.be/");
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);

                driver.findElement(By.id("login-overlay-button")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("passport3");
                    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("qwe123");
                driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();
        }
    }
```

getting exception while running this. its not able to find the elements by name or id

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"username"}
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.39.562718 (9a2698cba08cf5a471a29d30c8b3e12becabb0e9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds

Comment: Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.39.562718 (9a2698cba08cf5..., userDataDir: C:\Users\ivy4326\AppData\Lo...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP,

Comment: sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
 at

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
 at

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:317)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
 at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:188)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:309)
 at selinium.Bwinbe.main(Bwinbe.java:23)

Comment: Use `edit` option to update your question instead of posting comments

Comment: Don't clog the comment section, put Your stacktrace into question? provide some Html please.

Comment: @Chandru Please update your question properly with proper details, which element is getting error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be need to wait some times after clicking on login button. the following code may work for you.

```
public class Bwinbe {
     public static void main(String[] args) {    
         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "mypath");
         WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
         driver.get("http://test.www.bwin.be/");
         WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);

         driver.findElement(By.id("login-overlay-button")).click();
         wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("username")));
         driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("passport3");
         driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("qwe123");
         driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot buddy . this worked . had to add one more piece of code , it worked smooth

Comment: wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("submit")));

Answer (score 0):

As I saw page You are trying to automate, You are trying to login with button.

You should search by this element:

This is button html:

```
<a class="btn-s1" data-loading="Loading..." href="/en/authentication/loginoverlay" id="login-overlay-button" onclick="return false;" data-hasqtip="true" aria-describedby="qtip-0">LOG IN</a>
```

so try to search with

**`driver.findElement(By.className("btn-s1")).click();`**

then You have to switch to iFrame element to input username and password:

This is frame html:

```
  <iframe id="bcx_local_storage_frame" src="https://assets.bounceexchange.com/assets/bounce/local_storage_frame9.min.html#2582" style="display: none;" kwframeid="1"></iframe>
```

command would be something like this:

**driver.switchTo().frame("bcx_local_storage_frame");**

and then rest of Your code

```
   driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("passport3");
   driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("qwe123");
   driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: No frame element found by name or id bcx_local_storage_frame
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:03.216Z'
System info: host: 'IN01N01201', ip: '10.8.162.204', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.frame(RemoteWebDriver.java:876)
 at selinium.Bwinbe.main(Bwinbe.java:23)